# Trying to pass dynamic data from props to the inside of a text loaded from server (using MERN stack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I have some data returned from the server:
[
{ name: "example1", paragraph: "Some random text ${ValueIwantToPass}" },
etc
]

I fill textareas with these texts. I want in the front-end to pass dynamic the ${ValueIwantToPass} inside the text from props from other component and to be able to edit the text. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's work for you

make state

```
state={
response:[]
}
```

change server res to :

```
[ { name: "example1", paragraph: "Some random text" }, etc ]
```

(delete ${ValueIwantToPass} from res)

save server res to state

```
this.setState({response:res.data})
```

then change it:

```
var response=[...this.state.response]
var ValueWantToPass=this.prop.ValueWantToPass
response[0].paragraph += ValueWantToPass
this.setState({response})
```

Comment: It isnt necessary that everytime the value is at the end of the paragraph. Maybe it is "Some ${randomValue} and some random text"